# Can I drive in the United States with a Sri Lankan driver's license?

Tags: usa, legal, driving-licenses, washington-dc, sri-lankan-citizens

I'm currently in the United States for a short period and would like to know if my local driving license, which was issued in Sri Lanka, would be valid to drive a vehicle here in D.C., United States.

Do I need to convert my license to any other format (Like international driving license)?

Comment: What state will you be driving in? Each state has their own laws regarding foreign drivers.

Comment: District of Colombia (DC)

Comment: I can't find anything on the DC DMV site. Have you tried calling them?

Comment: As a driver licenced by Sri Lanka, you can only get an international driving permit in Sri Lanka.  But since your license seems to be in English (if image searches are to be trusted), you should be fine without one.

Comment: @MichaelC. No, I didn't call them.

Comment: @phoog Yes, My license is in English and it has a chip as well.

Comment: The chip is likely to be useless since as far as I know nobody in the US will be able to read the chip.

Comment: Things have moved on, my Sri Lankan licence was typed on a piece of card.

Answer (score 4):

All states in the US have their own rules regarding foreign drivers. If you are a resident in any state then you need that state's driving licenses. The rules to determine if you are a resident can be obtained from the respective state's DMV. Since you are on a short visit, I will assume you do not fulfill the resident criteria.

Talking specifically about District of Columbia (DC), USA

> Non-US citizens on visitor visas are not eligible to obtain driver
>   licenses in the District of Columbia. [source](https://dmv.dc.gov/service/driver-license-for-non-us-citizens)

If you are a visitor, you cannot apply for a DC drivers license. Period. However, in order to drive, you will need a valid driver's license issued by your home country and it should be in English. If it is not in English you can have it translated by your local embassy on an official embassy letterhead OR from a translation company.

> If your valid, non-US driver license is not in English, you must
>   attach an English translation from your embassy or from a translation
>   company. The embassy translation must be on official embassy
>   letterhead. The date of the translation must be on or after the actual
>   date of the non-English language driver license. Translations from
>   companies must be certified with a translation stamp, or notarized by
>   preparing a notarized affidavit confirming the translation was
>   prepared by a qualified translator and that it is both accurate and
>   complete. [source](https://dmv.dc.gov/service/driver-license-for-non-us-citizens)

Some states require an IDP (international driving permit) along with your valid license. However, the DC DMV does not mention any IDP requirements. If you will drive over into another state  e.g. Virginia, Maryland etc (which are really close by) you should check their DMV information. But it never hurts to have an IDP as an extra precaution, after all, it's not your own country.

> **Foreign Nationals Driving in the United States**
>
> People who drive in the
>   U.S. must have a valid driver's license. Some states require an
>   International Driving Permit (IDP) from foreign nationals, in addition
>   to a valid license from your own country. Contact the motor vehicle
>   department of each state you will drive in for its requirements.
>
> Short-Term Visitors If you intend on getting an IDP, you must do so in
>   advance of your travel:
>
> - The United States does not issue IDPs to foreign visitors. To get an    IDP, contact the motor vehicle department of the country that
>     issued your driver's license.
> - If you want to rent a car, you may need both your license and an IDP.    Find out the rental company's policies and other requirements
>     in advance.
>
> [source](https://www.usa.gov/visitors-driving)

All of the links that I have quoted are official US government websites. A [google search](https://washington.org/groups/dc-information/washington-dc-information-international-visitors) also leads to a website: [www.washington.org](http://www.washington.org); please note that this is a marketing organization for DC and not a US government website.

I would suggest contacting the DC DMV for any additional/official details:

> Phone: (202) 737-4404
>
> Email: dmv@dc.gov
>
> Live Chat: https://dmv.dc.gov/page/dmv-live-chat

Comment: For completeness, even those states that require IDPs waive the requirement for certain countries (e.g. Canada).

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](https://washington.org/groups/DC-information/washington-dc-information-international-visitors) guide, you will need to apply for an International Driver Permit before being able to drive in Washington, D.C. You can contact you local DMV for instructions on how to obtain an IDP.

Comment: The requirements vary by state. Your statement is very emphatic and makes it sound like you will always need an IDP.

Comment: The guide I posted is pursuant to Washington, D.C. specifically, but the guide does say international drivers need an IDP full stop. I've updated my answer to make it more specific to Washington, D.C. Can you cite a situation where an international driver would not need an IDP?

Comment: [California](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/dl/dl_info#international): "The State of California does not recognize an International Driving Permit (IDP) as a valid driver license. California does recognize a valid driver license that is issued by a foreign jurisdiction (country, state, territory) of which the license holder is a resident.

The IDP is only a translation of information contained on a person's foreign driver license and is not required to operate a motor vehicle in California."

Comment: IDP is NOT a driver's license. It's merely a piece of paper that essentially provides a translation of your driver's license into English and/or other languages. It's NOT a legal document. And oh, your answer is irrelevant anyway as the question is about the state of Washington, NOT Washington, District of Columbia. Where btw we're driven numerous times with Dutch licenses, no IDP required.

Comment: IDPs are issued by authorities in the country that issues the license, not where you are driving.

Comment: Why the downvotes? https://dmv.dc.gov/service/driver-license-for-non-us-citizens says "If you reside in the District for more than 30 days and you are NOT staying in the US on a visitor’s visa, you must get a DC DMV driver license." This suggests to me that DC follows the general rule of the individual states that a tourist who holds a valid driver's license from another country may drive for a limited time, or until s/he becomes a resident.

Comment: @jwenting What makes you think the question is about Washington state, not DC?

Comment: @jw OP clarified in comments that it's about DC.